# Only running software in Android simulator, Scrollview nested flatlist, unable to scroll

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I use srcollview to nest flatlist to render data. After the rendering is successful, however, when running on Android, the view cannot be scrolled, but running on IOS does not.

```js
<View >
  <FlatList
    data={categoryState}
    renderItem={item => <ItemCombination data={item} click={loading} detail={detail} />}
    listKey={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    numColumns={3}
    ListFooterComponent={
      <View style={{ width: 794, backgroundColor: '#fff', alignItems: 'center', maxHeight: 300 }} >
        {
          show ?
            showLoading ?
              <ActivityIndicator color='#21b6a8' size='large' style={{ marginVertical: 20 }} />
              :
              {/* unable to scroll */}
            <ScrollView style={{ width: Platform.OS === 'web' ? 780 : 794, height: 300 }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true} contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
              {/* unable to scroll */}
              <FlatList
                data={menuItems}
                renderItem={item => <Item data={item} click={menuItemClick} categoryId={categoryId} />}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id + index.toString()}
                numColumns={3}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              />
            </ScrollView>
          :
          <View></View>
        }
      </View>
    }
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the built-in [nestedscrollenabled](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled) prop for the children FlatList component.

```
<FlatList nestedScrollEnabled />
```

Nested scrolling is supported by default on iOS. so for android you need to add this.

Comment: `<ScrollView  nestedScrollEnabled />  `  
The problem is solved perfectly ！   thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flatlist in `ListFooterComponent` won't work in Android because It has Flatlist's scroll property which scrolls the container of the list with a footer also. Some workaround is like

```js
<FlatList
                    ......
ListFooterComponent={
<View style={{ width: 794, backgroundColor: '#fff', alignItems: 'center', maxHeight: 300 }} >
  {
    show ?
      showLoading ?
        <ActivityIndicator color='#21b6a8' size='large' style={{ marginVertical: 20 }} />
        :
        {/* remove scroll and have map on items to render data footer */}
      menuItems.map(item => { render <View> ...</View> }
    :
  }
</View>
}
/>
```